# Override variable in subclass in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, constructor

I have this super class:

```
abstract class Node(rawId: String) {
    open val id: String
    init {
        id = Base64.toBase64(this.javaClass.simpleName + "_" + rawId)
    }
}
```

And this subclass that extends Node:

```
data class Vendor (
    override var id: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val products: List<Product>?
): Node(id)
```

When I initialize the Vendor class like this:

```
new Vendor(vendor.getId(), vendor.getGroup().getName(), description, products);
```

I can see the init block in Node get fired as expected. However, when I get the id from the Vendor object, it is the rawId and not the encoded Id.

So I am a bit confused about the initialization order/logic in Kotlin classes. I want the encoding code to be common across all subclasses. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you are overriding the `id` field in the subclass and hence it would always remain the `rawId` value.

Since the base class has already an `id` field which has to be an encoded value, you don't need to override it in the subclass. You need to provide the `rawId` to the `Node` class in your `Vendor` class and let the base class take care of the `id` value to be instantiated with. You can have your abstract class as

```
abstract class Node(rawId: String) {
    val id: String = Base64.toBase64(this.javaClass.simpleName + "_" + rawId)
}
```

and then define your subclass as

```
data class Vendor (
    val rawId: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val products: List<Product>?
): Node(rawId)
```

Then with

```
Vendor newVendor = new Vendor(vendor.getId(), vendor.getGroup().getName(), description, products);
newVendor.getId() // would be the encoded id as you expect
```

since `Vendor` is a subclass of `Node`, the `id` field is also available to the `Vendor` object with the encoded value.